# How to animate options from Tools panel?

Tags: animation, selection-tools, properties

I wanted to add animation to Randomize option that can be accessed via Tools panel. When I click on it and go to the options it provides..(Amount, Uniform, normal, Random Seed) and press 'i' it says that 'offset' property cannot be be animated. Any workaround? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think it's possible with the current Blender architecture. Those are operator, they are runned once for all. There is no animation for those (as far as I know). But you can animate the results with shapekeys.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What are those? Can you point me to a tutorial where I can learn to animate operators with shapekeys?

Comment: When I come up against these, my workaround has been to substitute the object for it's clone at a certain frame #.  The clone is set up as required and independent of the original's settings.  It must be stressed that any properties inherited from the original that are not wanted, must be cleared from the duplicate's Outliner strips.

Comment: "*Can you point me to a tutorial where I can learn to animate operators*" You can't animate operators, operators are tools you run **once** and be done with it, they can't be animated because they are not saved anywhere